# Fetching images from an array of URLs and mapping them into new array (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, indexing, fetch

In my project, I have to fetch 20 images from The Met Digital Collection and display three random images.

In order to do that I tried to put every link into an array and fetching them with promise all.

The problem is that every image gets stored in the same value so I can´t call for a specific image in that array. Is it possible to get an index from `"const [url, setURL]"` or can I give the images an index at the same time as `"setURL(data.primaryImage)"`?

I am grateful for any help I can get!
:)

```js
const [url, setURL] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const urls = [
    'https://collectionapi.metmuseum.org/public/collection/v1/objects/250940',
    'https://collectionapi.metmuseum.org/public/collection/v1/objects/20622',
    'https://collectionapi.metmuseum.org/public/collection/v1/objects/436625',
    'https://collectionapi.metmuseum.org/public/collection/v1/objects/436444',
    'https://collectionapi.metmuseum.org/public/collection/v1/objects/436509',
    'https://collectionapi.metmuseum.org/public/collection/v1/objects/359245',
    'https://collectionapi.metmuseum.org/public/collection/v1/objects/459090',
    'https://collectionapi.metmuseum.org/public/collection/v1/objects/333933',
    'https://collectionapi.metmuseum.org/public/collection/v1/objects/333916',
    'https://collectionapi.metmuseum.org/public/collection/v1/objects/466350',
    'https://collectionapi.metmuseum.org/public/collection/v1/objects/44831',
    'https://collectionapi.metmuseum.org/public/collection/v1/objects/383010',
    'https://collectionapi.metmuseum.org/public/collection/v1/objects/202660',
    'https://collectionapi.metmuseum.org/public/collection/v1/objects/406317',
    'https://collectionapi.metmuseum.org/public/collection/v1/objects/337349',
    'https://collectionapi.metmuseum.org/public/collection/v1/objects/503448',
    'https://collectionapi.metmuseum.org/public/collection/v1/objects/12617',
    'https://collectionapi.metmuseum.org/public/collection/v1/objects/248662',
    'https://collectionapi.metmuseum.org/public/collection/v1/objects/435805',
    'https://collectionapi.metmuseum.org/public/collection/v1/objects/438545',
  ];

  Promise.all(
    urls.map((url) =>
      fetch(url)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => setURL(data.primaryImage))
        .catch((error) => console.log('There was a problem!', error))
    ),
    []
  );
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Promise.all(...).then(values => setURLs(values))` to atomically set your URLs array.

Here's a [Live Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-usestate-forked-vu5mm).

Code + some refactoring:

```js
const [urls, setURLs] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const urls = [
    250940,
    20622,
    436625,
    436444,
    436509,
    359245,
    459090,
    333933,
    333916,
    466350,
    44831,
    383010,
    202660,
    406317,
    337349,
    503448,
    12617,
    248662,
    435805,
    438545
  ].map(
    (itemId) =>
      `https://collectionapi.metmuseum.org/public/collection/v1/objects/${itemId}`
  );

  Promise.all(
    urls.map((currUrl) =>
      fetch(currUrl)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => data.primaryImage)
        .catch((error) => console.log("There was a problem!", error))
    )
  ).then((fetchedUrls) => setURLs(fetchedUrls));
}, []);
```

Comment: That solved it. Thank you for the help! :)